# iPhone Simulator folder not found in iOS 7, XCode 5

Tags: ios7, xcode5

Recently, I have upgraded my XCode to verion 5.0.1 from version 4.6.3, and my Mac to iOS 7.0.3 and iOS X Maverick.

I have a simple project with Core Data and it was written with Xocde 4.6.3 and run with iOS 6.1, and when I run it, I can go view the project sqlite file under path as  ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/[app GUID]/Documents/MyAppName.sqlite.

After I upgrade my Mac and XCode with new versions as I mentioned above, I open that project with XCode 5, and I am able to perform CRUD operations against Core Data functions used in my application, and the project runs OK.  However, I follow the path as above to take a look at my sqlite file, I **cannot** find out the 'iPhone Simulator' folder under the '~/Library/Application Support' folder.

Please help.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried logging the path for the documents directory?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

NSLog(@"%@",basePath);
```

**EDIT** 
If you can't see the Library folder, go to finder and press command + shift + G, and enter the output received from above log. in your case, /Users/thomaslee/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5482CD65-DA92-4C65-863C-2D1335C24C43/Documents

Comment: I see the debug output as "/Users/thomaslee/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5482CD65-DA92-4C65-863C-2D1335C24C43/Documents".  But if I use Finder, I do not see the "Library" folder under the "/Users/thomaslee/" folder. Any ideas?

Comment: @Thomas.Benz the Library folder under your home directory is hidden and thus is not seen in the Finder by default. You can open a finder to it by typing in "open ~/Library" in a terminal shell.

Comment: @Colin, thank you for your helps. Now I can see the folder, and I remove the "hidden" attribute of the folder by using command: chflags nohidden {path-to-folder}